# How to match email and apply xml code [xslt]

Tags: regex, xml, xslt

I am new to `XSLT`, Can anyone help to fetch the email id and phone number from the para tag and apply the appropriate email and phone tag to the text like this

```
<email>dames.vi_no192@server.home.com</email><contact>+999841xxxx</contact>
```

Please see the input and required output

**Source:**

```
<para>
This is the para text and this para contains email id is dames.vi_no192@server.home.com and contact number is +9998412122
</para>
```

**Required Output:**

```
<para>
This is the para text and this para contains emailid is <email>dames.vi_no192@server.home.com</email> and contact number is <contact>+9998412122</contact>
</para>
```

Comment: If you can use an XSLT 2.0 processor like Saxon 9 or XmlPrime then it is a job for `analyze-string`.

Comment: Thanks martin, I am using XSLT 2.0,  how to apply the pattern in regex for any email or phone number using analyze-string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example, mainly meant to show how to use `analyze-string`:

```
<xsl:template match="para">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="para//text()">
  <xsl:analyze-string select="." regex="(\w+[._])*\w+@(\w+\.)*\w+">
    <xsl:matching-substring>
      <email>
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
      </email>
    </xsl:matching-substring>
    <xsl:non-matching-substring>
      <xsl:analyze-string select="." regex="[+]{{0,2}}[0-9() ]*[0-9]+">
        <xsl:matching-substring>
          <contact>
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
          </contact>
        </xsl:matching-substring>
        <xsl:non-matching-substring>
          <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </xsl:non-matching-substring>
      </xsl:analyze-string>
    </xsl:non-matching-substring>
  </xsl:analyze-string>
</xsl:template>
```

Of course the real challenge is to write regular expressions that match all possible input pattern you expect for an email address or for a phone number, the above is not meant as complete solution for this.

The `\w` character class include digits, see the definition in http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-2/#charcter-classes which defines `\w` as `[#x0000-#x10FFFF]-[\p{P}\p{Z}\p{C}]` (all characters except the set of "punctuation", "separator" and "other" characters). As for the structure of the first pattern, it expects an zero or more sequences of word characters followed by a dot or an underline characters followed by a non-empty sequence of word characters followed by the at symbol `@` followed by zero or more sequences of word characters followed by a dot and finally a mandatory sequence of word characters.

The second pattern allows zero or up to two plus symbols, then a sequence of digits intermixed with parentheses and spaces and finally a mandatory sequence of digits. As said, the patterns serve as examples, for email addresses I guess there is a spec somewhere and for phone numbers you will need to decide which characters like spaces or parentheses you will allow to group digits.

Comment: Thanks martin, Perfectly working. But I need few more doubt on this, In first analyze-string regex, the number is not matched (\d) then how the output works perfectly? and last can you explain the first and second regex if possible? Sorry It may be silly to intermediate I am sorry,  I am a beginner to XSLT.

Comment: @NachiappanR, I have edited the answer and added some explanation and a link to the formal specification of the regular expression language that XPath and XSLT 2.0 share with XML schemas.

Comment: Thanks Martin for the explanation, one more thing, did we can both the email and number on same expression using regex-group, I read some where but I don`t implement it exactly. Can you help on this.